# Laravel - sharing controllers while changing the redirect route and views?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a banned user controller in the moderation panel where a moderator can ban a specific user. In the admin panel, I have to use the same views and same controller methods. I don't want to duplicate the controller for admin panel and change the redirect route and stuff.

For instance, in my `BanController`, I have the following:

```
public function index() {
    return view('mod.ban.index')
}

public function ban(User $user) {
   // Ban user
   // Redirect back to the new ban page
   redirect(route('mod.ban.show', $user->ban->id)); 
}

public function unban(User $user) {
    // Unban user
   // Redirect back to the new ban page
   redirect(route('mod.ban.show, $user->ban->id));
}
```

As you can see, the redirect route  and views are for moderation only.  The views extend to the mod layout in moderation panel. I cannot find a way to share the views between the admin and mod panel unless I store the contents in a partial view. I can overcome this problem easily but the redirection is the main problem here. If I use one controller for both, when it comes to redirection, the admin may be redirected to the mod panel while he is managing a ban from admin panel and vice versa.

How can I best solve this problem? Thank you!

How can I use the same controller logic and use it in both moderation panel and admin panel? Thanks a ton!

Comment: is your moderation and admin panel is in different project ? if so, you can use package to share your ban feature in your project

Comment: It's a same project

Comment: How are you managing `admin` and `moderator` role currently? I guess there must be something implemented for it

Comment: Simply using 3 tables - pivot, permissions and times: pivot attaching a role with permission